# JS Split Varables

Tags: javascript, string, while-loop, switch-statement

I have a String like "iyxnhel2jeh" and i want to for each 2 byte I want to split those into a single var.

```js
var string = "iyxnhel2jehe";
var final = "";

while (/*String still has bits*/) {
    switch (/*Two byte of string*/) {
        case "iy":
            final += "x";
        break;
        case "xn":
            final += "o";
        break;
        case "he":
            final += "g";
        break;
        case "l2":
            final += "k";
        break;
        case "je":
            final += "e";
        break;
        default:
            final += "none"
    }
}
```

Whats the best way to cut this string?

Comment: The number of bytes for a given character depends on the encoding... Do you mean you just want to slice a string every two characters?

Comment: Do you mean `bytes`, or do you actually mean `characters`?

Comment: This could be done with if statements with indexOf and an else instead of a loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use regex to split string into 2letter parts, map them onto the characters from switch statement and join array back together, however the optimal way to do that would be to get rid of the switch statement and instead use those sequences of characters as keys of a object.

```js
var string = "iyxnhel2jehe";
var final = string.match(/.{1,2}/g).map(twoletters => {
    return {
        "iy": "x",
        "xn": "o",
        "he": "g",
        "l2": "k",
        "je": "e"
    }[twoletters] || "none";
}).join("");
console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about the best way, but the following would do what you want...

```js
var string = "iyxnhel2jehe";
var final = "";

for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i+=2) {
  switch (string.substr(i,2)) {
        case "iy":
            final += "x";
        break;
        case "xn":
            final += "o";
        break;
        case "he":
            final += "g";
        break;
        case "l2":
            final += "k";
        break;
        case "je":
            final += "e";
        break;
        default:
            final += "none"
   }
}
console.log(final);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var string = "iyxnhel2jehe";
var final = "";
var offset = 0;
while (offset < string.length) {
 switch (string.slice(offset, offset + 2)) {
  case "iy":
   final += "x";
   break;
  case "xn":
   final += "o";
   break;
  case "he":
   final += "g";
   break;
  case "l2":
   final += "k";
   break;
  case "je":
   final += "e";
   break;
  default:
   final += "none"
 }
 offset += 2;
}
console.log(final);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to consume characters and check whether there are still any left, try splitting the string into 2-character chunks first, and loop through the array:

```js
const s = "iyxnhel2jehe";
let final = "";

const t = s.split('');
const segments = t.map((e, i) => i % 2 === 0 ?
                                 e + (t.length - 1 >= i + 1 ? t[i + 1] : '') :
                                 null)
                  .filter(x => x != null);

segments.forEach(sg => {
    console.log(sg);
    switch (sg) {
        case "iy":
            final += "x";
        break;
        case "xn":
            final += "o";
        break;
        case "he":
            final += "g";
        break;
        case "l2":
            final += "k";
        break;
        case "je":
            final += "e";
        break;
        default:
            final += "none"
    }
});

console.log(final);
```